# Storing a Pic in The project folder, windows Phone 8.0, c#, xaml

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, save, directory

I want to take a picture with the CameraCaptureTask, and then save it in a specific folder, in my Project(!). I found some Tutorials, where you can save a pic in the MediaLibrary. But i want to store it  right in the Project.
I have the Image as a Bitmap in my code, just have to save it now.
I would really apreciate a tip.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in three ways

1. Using Isolated Storage

   Here you just get the stream of the captured image and store it in Isolated Storage as shown here
    [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-captured-image/)
2. Using Memory Stream

   Here you store the captured image stream in the memory

   ```
     using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               bitmap2.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100); //Don't change other unless necessary
               stream.Close();

           }
   ```
3. Using Local Folder Storage

   Here you save the captured image stream in Local Folder of your App

   ```
             StorageFile sampleFile = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.png");
               await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, capturedImageStream);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i just have one problem. SystemIO seems not to be implemented in Windows Phone 8.0